# Tabular Editor 3: Apply changes from tabular editor 3 to power bi desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new at using tabular editor so need some help, So from a power by desktop file I open tabular editor 3, I add some measures which I am copying from another pbix file open on another tabular editor instance. In the tabular editor file where I have pasted the measures I click on file -> close model and also save it. When I go back to Power Bi Desktop it asks me to apply changes or discard changes I click on apply changes and the changes disapper and I cannot see the measures I just added. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my question so you have to click on save back to database which syncs the pbix file with the tabular editor.